# Creating a hyperlink to a manual workflow start on a list item in a custom list for SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, hyperlink

I am creating a training signup.  The trainings are in a custom list as list items.  I have two workflows on this custom list both in SPD.  My first workflow creates a calendar event upon creation of a new list item.  My other workflow is called Add Participant which adds a participant to the list item and sends them a calendar invite to the training.  In this first workflow I would like it to also populate a column upon creation of the list item in each list item with a hyperlink to be able to run the Add Participant workflow directly.  Then I would like to create a display template to bring in the columns and create a button out of that hyperlink so that when a user views the page with all available trainings, it has a signup button that starts the Add Participant workflow.

What I'm running into is that I can not find the link to that manual start of the workflow in SPO.  I have read previous posts from what appears to be 2007 and 2010 SP, but SPO doesn't appear to be calling a link.  Anyone have any ideas on how to get this link or how to kick off this workflow?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Online uses javascript (JSOM) to kick start workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 uses JavaScript/CSOM to Start Workflows.

Read this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607127/Using-SharePoint-Workflow-Services-JS-API

And invoke the JavaScript instead of link.